# How to delete uncomitted row? Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, multithreading

I have two transactions:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable  WHERE status = 'NEW' and expire_date = CURRENT_DATE LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

This transaction locks the row with id =1

And in parallel, I'm executing this transaction (first transaction is not comitted)

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=1;
```

But it just freezes and waits the ending of the first transaction.
Is there a way to delete a locked row without waiting for the end of the first transaction?

Posgres version 13.2

P.S. I'm using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to prevent another thread of my service(multithreaded) from selecting the same row

Comment: Stop the transaction, or use pg_terminate_backend() to kill it. But you can't delete a row that is locked by another transaction, that would destroy all benefits from transactions.

Comment: You will have to terminate the running transaction to be able to delete the locked row. Anything other than that would defeat the purpose of data integrity.